# How do you cast unsigned short data[32] to unsigned char* very fast

Tags: c++, c, optimization

If you had to convert

```
unsigned short data1[32]
```

to

```
unsigned char* data2
```

in a tight loop to be executed 10 million times
what function would you use to get the best performance? 
I am using this

```
reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(data1);
```

but was wondering if there is a better way

Comment: What's in data1 and what do you expect in data2 to be after conversion?

Comment: @yi_H  UTF-8 encoded string in both data1 and data2

Comment: UTF-8 in short? that doesn't look good

Comment: @yi_H I am happy with the answers provided.

Comment: yi_H was referring to the fact that not all UTF-8 characters can be stored in only 2 bytes, you may have new problems :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`reinterpret_cast` is the holy grail of performance seeking coders, namely code that results in zero clock cycles.

Answer (score 2):

Casting with `reinterpret_cast` or `(unsigned char*)` will not output ANY assembly instruction. Therefore no time loss.

Answer (score 2):

A reinterpret_cast doesn't generate any code.  It simply converts how the compiler treats the data in the registers or memory.  There is no better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Casting is not a lexical conversion.

You may need to use a function like `itoa` or if windows dependencies are out you might be able to use `boost::lexical_cast`

Depends what your goal is, not sure about fastest or best way myself.

**Edit:** In response to OP's comment that this data is a UTF-8 string.

The `reinterpret_cast` is not sufficient then, neither is my original answer. You will need to use the correct encoding to convert your string. Characters 0-127 of UTF-8 are compatible as single byte chars which is the equivalent of ANSI (i.e. 41 is 'A')

However anything beyond that will require conversion. UTF-8 can use 2-6 bytes for the characters beyond 127 to support the storage of extended languages.

Answer (score 0):

For the most part, types is a concept of the compiler more than the machine code.

Interpreting bytes as a specific type is just a matter of what the machine code instructions expect to be at certain addresses.

Casting a type to another (apart from `dynamic_cast`) does not generate any actual code. The exception is when you're casting between types within the same hierarchy, in which case the cast may produce a pointer offset.